# One to Many Relationship setting another value to false

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 forms. One is called Help and another is called HelpSolution. Help can have many Solutions. Here's their models.

```
public class Help
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Priority? Priority { get; set; }
    public bool Condition { get; set; }
    public int? EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public int? HelpCategoryID { get; set; }
    public int? HelpTypeID { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public virtual HelpCategory HelpCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual HelpType HelpType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<HelpSolution> HelpSolutions { get; set; }
}
```

(yes, I know, it has a lot of values, most are not important here, but the last one)

```
public class HelpSolution
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Solution { get; set; }
    public virtual int? HelpID { get; set; }
    public virtual Help Help { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }

}
```

In the Help View I created a new Action called Submit where I basically confirm which solutions are valid using checkboxes. In that form I display the solutions of that specific help (using HelpID) in checkboxes. I want to do a form where I submit, press on the checkbox and it changes HelpSolution value in database from **false to true**, because I am diferentiating that it has been selected as a valid solution (help can have many solutions and many valid ones).

I created an ActionResult in the Controller, but It's pretty rubbish so I came here to ask help of how could I do this? Any help is highly appreciated.

Here's the Action:

```
public ActionResult Submit(int id)
    {
       HelpViewModel help = Mapper.Map<Help, 
       HelpViewModel(unitOfWork.HelpRepository.GetByID(id));
        if (help == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(help);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Submit(HelpViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            Help help = Mapper.Map<Help>(model);
            AddOrUpdateSolutions(help, model.HelpSolutions);
            unitOfWork.HelpRepository.Update(help);
            unitOfWork.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = model.ID });
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

The action where I try to set the value is AddOrUpdateSolutions but I wrote it pretty bad so I don't think it would help. I just need to know how should I go about doing this thing.

Comment: [Here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/update-one-to-many-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx) is one way to update a child collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a solution by myself, probably it's pretty bad, but it works and I have no other ideas.

```
    public ActionResult Submit(int id)
    {
        HelpViewModel help = Mapper.Map<Help, HelpViewModel>(unitOfWork.HelpRepository.GetByID(id));
        if (help == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(help);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Submit(HelpViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Help help = Mapper.Map<HelpViewModel,Help>(model);
            model.HelpSolutions = PopulateSolutionData(model.ID);

            foreach (var solution in help.HelpSolutions)
            {
                var entityItem = db.HelpSolutions.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ID == solution.ID);
                if (solution.Selected == true){
                        entityItem.Selected = true;
                }
                else{
                    entityItem.Selected = false;
                }
                db.Entry(entityItem).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = model.ID });
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

PopulateSolutionData just populates the Solutions from the database and sets them all to false. Basically what fixed this problem was using db and not UnitOfWork, and just setting values with an if and setting the entitystate to modified.